# How to wait until directories having files get deleted recursively in C#

Tags: c#, directory

I am deleting couple of folders which containing lot of files.
Then I create these folders again.
Now the problem is sometimes directory takes time to get deleted.

But before I create a directory I check whether directory exists or not. So problem arises here is that it already exists and it doesn't create directory again.

```
if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {

                Directory.Delete(path, true);
            }
 if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {

                dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                dir.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.Hidden;
            }
```

Comment: Why are you deleting the directory? Anyway, the simplest solution to me would be to rename the directory (move it to a new location in the same parent folder), and then delete the renamed directory. That way if a new one gets created, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @John Alright sounds good. By the way I am using these as temporary directories. I merge all files available in this directory for different scenarios. The reason why I am deleting it and creating again so that I can get all files I need to merge again.

Comment: If using temporary directories, have you considered using a memorystream and storing file information there? Its alot more effficient than using the filesystem because of the number of exceptions the filesystem can give you (ie locking files, disk space, file no longer exists, access permissions etc). Using memorystreams will reduce wear and tear on the hard drive, be faster and less issues (assuming the files aren't so big they consume all ram).

Comment: Please explain "How to wait ..." - your code is synchron = blocking - it is waiting because of its nature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a filewatcher. See here: [https://www.infoworld.com/article/3185447/how-to-work-with-filesystemwatcher-in-c.html]

The code from their article but modified to your question is:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileWatcherExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"c:\example";
            MonitorDirectory(path);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
            fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += (o,s) => Console.WriteLine("File deleted: {0}", e.Name);
            fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The file watcher allows for create, modify and delete events allowing you to permanently get real time updates on changes to a folder or file.